# System getting to command prompt soon after booting

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

My system is getting to command prompt soon after the booting process. 
Once getting into command prompt, the cursor stops at DHCP....../, I have to press escape to proceed further.
I'm using Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Kindly advice

Comment: can you please  add more details or maybe a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is either set to boot from the network before the hard drive, or it can't see the hard drive. Try and interrupt the boot process into BIOS and correct the boot order, or if there is a boot menu select the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting into the F12 network boot process. I suggest going into your BIOS and disabling network boot.